# Combining two consecutive elements in a Flux

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'd like to do something similar to `zipWith`, but I'd like to zip a stream of elements with itself and an offset of one. In other words, I want to create a stream of elements, each of which is the combination of two consecutive elements from the original stream.

**Example:**

I to transform a Flux like this:

```java
final var events = Flux.just(10, 20, 30, 40);
```

into a Flux that consists of these tuples (e.g. using `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair` or so):

```
[(10, 20), (20, 30), (30, 40)]
```

The new stream's total length would be `n-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found an answer myself.

```java
final var events = Flux.just(10, 20, 30, 40);
final var tuples = events.zipWith(events.skip(1));
```

Answer (score 3):

Look into `buffer`:

```
events.buffer(2, 1);
```

This produces buffers of size `2`, and open a buffer on every element (`1`).
Note that in case of even number of source elements, the last buffer will contain a single entry:

```
[[10, 20], [20, 30], [30, 40], [40]]
```

It can then be eliminated by a `filter`:

```
events.buffer(2, 1)
    .filter(b -> b.size() > 1);
```

Which produces:

```
[[10, 20], [20, 30], [30, 40]]
```